# Correct mapping for SHChangeNotify in JNA

Tags: java, jna

This is syntax for SHChangeNotify function from MSDN:

```
void SHChangeNotify(
  LONG wEventId,
  UINT uFlags,
  __in_opt  LPCVOID dwItem1,
  __in_opt  LPCVOID dwItem2
);
```

I've to write its Java counterpart in Java Native Access [JNA], but this declaration seems to be wrong:

```
public interface Shell32 extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32 {

    public Shell32 INSTANCE = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary(Shell32.class);

    void SHChangeNotify(long wEventId, int uFlags, Pointer dwItem1, Pointer dwItem2);

}
```

I got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error
>   looking up function 'SHChangeNotify'

Any idea how to write it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending Shell32 interface from `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32`, extends it from `StdCallLibrary`

```
public interface Shell32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    final static Map<String, Object> WIN32API_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        {
            put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    public Shell32 INSTANCE = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("Shell32", Shell32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS);

    //whatever you want to expose here
}
```

Comment: The problem was with public Shell32 INSTANCE = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("Shell32", Shell32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS); I forgot to add this argument: "Shell32".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with deriving from the original Shell32, but you need to call Native.loadLibrary in the same way that the original Shell32 calls it.


In addition, your first argument should be a 32-bit quantity, not a 64-bit.  The win32 platform library includes a definition for LONG, or you can simply use Java "int".

Comment: @technomage, you first sentence is valid as OP has commented that it works no matter what the interface is extended from. The mistake is just forgetting the library name string.  But, I try to make sense of the rest that you've commented. With regard to using Java `int` type for the first argument of `SHChangeNotify`; your suggested Java `int` type will definitely cause `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`; nevertheless, I will prefer the use of Java `long` instead of `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LONG` since the former works flawlessly in my unit test.